# Google cloud Ruby: Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs. It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a rails app im trying to deploy to the google cloud platform. It gets to a certain point and then times out. I ran it a few times but it gives the same error each time.

```
The push refers to a repository [us.gcr.io/site-1286/appengine/default.20160504t151124] (len: 1)
a12739e07554: Preparing
a12739e07554: Pushing
a12739e07554: Pushed
6caf2d2e404b: Preparing
6caf2d2e404b: Pushing
6caf2d2e404b: Pushed
9ae35a0da566: Preparing
9ae35a0da566: Pushing
9ae35a0da566: Pushed
1e540bceeb97: Preparing
1e540bceeb97: Pushing
1e540bceeb97: Pushed
2bed01823074: Preparing
2bed01823074: Pushing
2bed01823074: Pushed
c27bdbcec1bd: Preparing
c27bdbcec1bd: Pushing
c27bdbcec1bd: Pushed
0bfc47188461: Image already exists
ef866b7acceb: Image already exists
b5af07c62198: Image already exists
b3388c4bd40b: Image already exists
437045486895: Image already exists
58d9f8b0627d: Image already exists
f8f0a08927ad: Image already exists
502312a1defd: Image already exists
f28dbda953c1: Image already exists
096d9403d234: Image already exists
latest: digest: sha256:a467b3258f8bb820ccf12ec29282869902522c7c4d790e7290aed6c1d8f0d1f7 size: 69944
DONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
Roberts-MBP:site Robert$
```

At this point I don't know what needs to be changed. I have enables all the API's that I think I need to enable, the bucket is made and setup, the dependencies are on the server (well at the ones i'm aware of) , the SQL db is up and working with `rake db:setup` working fine. So I think my problem lies in my app.yaml file considering I dont really know everything that is supposed to go in there.

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
vm: true
entrypoint: bundle exec rackup -p 8080 -E production config.ru
resources:
  cpu: 0.5
  memory_gb: 1.3
  disk_size_gb: 10

env_variables:
  GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: site-1286.appspot.com
```

Maybe its missing info or something I dont know. I do have 2 instances I have manually created hoping the app would deploy on them but it seems to create other instacnes when I run the deploy maybe thats the reason?

I'm not too familiar with deploying to VM servers and I'm new to google cloud so I'm at a loss of what could be causing this error.

Answer (score 3):

The key part of the error message is "It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.": this means that your application isn't passing [health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-instances-are-managed#health_checking). Take a look at your application logs (in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)) to help diagnose.

Comment: I'm looking at the logs but they dont really say anything. They are hard to understand what they mean. Plus when I use the filter to show critical errors in the logs there are no results